# Access to template scope from isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to implement an AngularJS directive which has it own isolated scope in order to make it reusable in the same page. This directive is described by a template which is in another file so I use the templateUrl option.

```
app.directive('inputSettings', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/admin/inputSettingsTemplate.html',
        controller: 'InputSettingsCtrl',
        scope: {
            settingkey: '=',
            value: '=',
            range: '=',
            check: '=',
            autosave: '='
        }
    };
});
```

In this template, I have a form named `form`.

```
<form name="form" class="settingForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.input.$invalid, 'has-success' : form.input.$valid }">
        <input class="form-control" name="input" type="text" ng-model="valueInput" />
        <p ng-show="form.input.$invalid && !form.input.$pristine" class="help-block" translate="{{ 'inputSettingErrorMessage' | translate:translationData }}"></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem I have is that I want to be able to set the validity of the input inside the template using a code like the following in the controller of my directive :

```
$scope.form.input.$setValidity("input", true);
```

But I have an error when I try to execute such a code. It seems that `$scope` does not know the form so I can't interact with my form within the controller of my directive.

Have you any idea? Is there anything I did wrong?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: when are you trying to execute this code? directly during controller initialization?

Comment: No in a watcher of the $scope.valueInput variable. Actually, I want to update the validity of the input when the value is changed.

Comment: I would suggest checking that the new value is different from the old value. It might be the case that the watcher is triggered anyway on the first time (during init) and at that point the form is not on the scope yet since the controller is run before the linking

Comment: I don't think this is the problem because the error occurs only when I try to change the value inside the input. So the initialization is done since a while I guess.

Comment: Mind putting up a plunkr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I manage to make my code works with a minimum amount of changes. I don't know if it is the good answer but it works like a charm for me.

I simply replaced the `<form>` tag by the `<ng-form>` and now it works perfectly. It means that the controller of my directive now can access to the form by it name.

Comment: was you directive inside another <form> tag? That would explain the issue

Comment: Yes it is ! I guess that there was conflict between the parent form and the one in the directive. Is it a bad idea to have nested forms? Should I delete the one in my template directive?

Comment: Ng-form allows nesting, where form does not. Form should only be the topmost one and can have any number or depth of ng-form children.

Comment: And has the form access to inputs in ng-forms?

Comment: In a nested manner, but it's been too long ago for me to remember the details. Basically form is an alias of ng-form with some details.

Comment: Thank you for your time ! You really helped me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generally in a directive , to set the validity of a element we require ngModel for the directive and then we try to set the $validity of the element using the ngModelController

Comment: Have you any example that would allow me to understand what you mean? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have your controller for that directory, you can use that controller in order to manipulate the data.

```
function InputSettingsCtrl(){
  var vm = this;
  console.log(vm);
}
```

Also remember to add the controllerAs to your directive

```
controllerAs: 'ctrl',
```

Like this you can bind the variable from the controller to the view

Answer (score -2):

Use $rootScope. It`s global. It contains all $scopeS..
Like

```
$rootScope.data = data; $scope.data = $rootScope.data
```